# Possible to read the selection of a subgrid in CRM2011?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm trying to be able to retreieve the selection of a SubGrid at the exact moment a user selects it. For example, add an EventListener OnClick that would make a JS function run in the background to do X thing when a subgrid element/row is selected without having to click Save or another button to run the function. Ive been searching online and alot of links appear for retrieving ALL records in a subgrid but none really show if one can add an EventListener. Another possibility would be to intercept when a subgrid is focused on and make that run a function. What do you guys think would be possible, always trying to keep the methods the supported way. :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your willing to be a little creative, you could try the following:

1. Add a custom ribbon button.
2. Add an enable rule to that ribbon button that calls a JavaScript library.
3. Add your logic into that JavaScript library.
4. When a record is selected in the sub grid, CRM will refresh the ribbon and call your enable rule.

I've only just thought of that so I don't know if it will work, but worth a try.

If that fails then I don't know any other supported way to have an OnClick event.

---

Edit, I've had a play and it does appear to be possible, see my blog post here: [CRM 2013 Adding an On Change Event to a Grid View](http://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/crm-2013-adding-an-on-change-event-to-a-sub-grid/). Its for CRM 2013, but I believe can be adapted for CRM 2011 (see my note at the end).

Comment: Hehe, yeah. Been looking around and apparently the only supported way would be like that. Been having a go with some "unsupported" methods, I'll let you know what I come up with. If anything else pops up, ANYTHING, let me know :P.

Comment: No event is fired when a user select a sub-grid item. Slipping code into the enable rule is interesting, it will probably only fire when the subgrid gets focus and not if the user selects another item in the subgrid. @Hector please keep us updated.